# Cannot find systemd unit files in Xubuntu 15.04

Tags: xubuntu, 15.04, systemd

Does Xubuntu 15.04 really run on `systemd`?

I noticed that there is no single unit file available in newly released Xubuntu 15.04, although they are available in both Kubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu 15.04.

This can be confirmed with no output of command `systemctl list-unit-files`. Further, if I do, for example, `systemctl status sshd`, it will point to old init based scripts at /etc/init.d/ directory.

This is really confusing as the people at Canonical confirmed that `systemd` will be the default init program for their upcoming releases.

My question is why do Kubuntu & Ubuntu run `systemd` correctly and not Xubuntu?

Comment: Perhaps the people be hind Xubuntu decided to stick with apstart. Why? Why not?

Comment: I think you are probably right.